# Need to break my main method into smaller methods

Tags: java

I have written the following code for a lab assignment, however, my professor wants me to break my main method down into other methods and call those methods in the main method. I tried creating methods for creating the input and output streams, and I tried to create a method for the actual writing of the reverse file but I am getting no where. Can someone point me in the right direction? do I need to create another class that I will instantiate and call these methods on? I'm new to java, so any help is appreciated!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Reads lines of text from a file named testclass.txt and writes them to a file
 * named output.txt in reverse order.
 */

public class ReverseFile {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner fileRead;     // input stream for reading text file.
      PrintWriter fileWrite;  // output stream for writing text file.

      ArrayList<String> fileLines;  // An ArrayList for holding the lines of the text file.
      fileLines = new ArrayList<String>();

      try {  // Create the input stream.
         fileRead = new Scanner(new File("testclass.txt"));
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("Can't find text file");
         return;  // End the program by returning from main().
      }

      try {  // Create the output stream.
         fileWrite = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("Can't open file output.txt");
         System.out.println("Error: " + e);
         fileRead.close();  // Close the input file.
         return;        // End the program.
      }

      while ( fileRead.hasNextLine() ) {  // Read until end-of-file.
         String textLine = fileRead.nextLine();
         System.out.println(textLine);
         fileLines.add(textLine);
      }

      // Output the text in reverse order.

      for (int i = fileLines.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
         fileWrite.println(fileLines.get(i));
         //System.out.println(reverseLines);


      System.out.println("Done, check output.txt");

      fileRead.close();
      fileWrite.close();

   }  // end of main()

}
```

Comment: Use an IDE (like eclipse) that has ["extract method"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Extract_method_revival) for refactoring.

Comment: where are the other methods that you wrote? What error do you get on those methods?

Comment: Some of your comments identify logical chunks of functionality that you could split into other methods.

Comment: do you not know the syntax of how to create other methods? or are you seeing an error?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally each method should do one thing only and have a name that makes it clear what that one thing is.

My suggestion is that your main method should look something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> lines = createAndReadInputStream();
    reverse(lines);
    createAndWriteOutputStream(lines);
}
```

That makes it perfectly clear to the reader exactly what the method does and all implementation details are in other methods.

Then do the same for the next method:

```
private List<String> createAndReadInputStream() {
    Scanner inputScanner = createInputStream();
    return scanToLines(inputScanner);
}
```

And so on. If correctly structured your class variables all become locally scoped variables and your code is straightforward and easy to read. You'll also find you need far fewer comments to explain what's happening: the names of the methods are generally enough on their own.

If you are interested in learning more about why your professor asked for this, and how to go about doing it, I highly recommend the book "Clean Code" by Robert Martin. The software development team of which I am a part (80 people in 11 agile teams) adopted it several years ago and the quality, readability and maintainability of our code has improved out of sight. While it takes some getting used to it's worth the effort. In my view the old adage that more code means more bugs is just completely false - as long as the extra code is there for readability, testability, maintainability then it means fewer bugs not more.

Comment: Thank you for the book recommendation, luckily we have it in my school's library and I will definitely give it a look

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.  Move this section of code:

```
  try {  // Create the input stream.
     fileRead = new Scanner(new File("testclass.txt"));
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     System.out.println("Can't find text file");
     return;  // End the program by returning from main().
  }
```

into a new private method called createInputStream within the ReverseFile class.  Call the new member from the point in the code where you removed the section. Don't forget to return "fileRead" from the method.

Answer (score -1):

What about this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/** * Reads lines of text from a file named testclass.txt and writes them to a file * named output.txt in reverse order. */

public class ReverseFile {

    public static ArrayList<String> readFile(String fileName) {
        Scanner fileRead; // Scanner for reading text file.

        // Try to open file for reading
        try {
            fileRead = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

        // On failure -> print message & return null
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {       
            System.out.println("Can't find text file");
            return null;
        }

        // Create ArrayList for readed lines
        ArrayList<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<String>();    

        // Read file line-by-line until end-of-file.
        while ( fileRead.hasNextLine() ) {
            String textLine = fileRead.nextLine(); // Read next line
            System.out.println(textLine); // Print line to terminal
            fileLines.add(textLine); // Add line to ArrayList
        }

        // Close scanner -> will close allso opened file
        fileRead.close();

        // Return loaded lines
        return fileLines;
    }

    public static void createReversedFile(String filename, ArrayList<String> fileLines) {
        PrintWriter fileWrite;  // PrintWriter for writing text file.

        // Try to open file for writing
        try {  
            fileWrite = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

        // On failure -> print message & return
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't open file output.txt");
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            fileRead.close();  // Close the input file.
            return;
        }

        // Output the text in reverse order
        for (int i = fileLines.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            fileWrite.println(fileLines.get(i));
            //System.out.println(reverseLines);
        }


        System.out.println("Done, check " + filename);

        // Close PrintWriter -> will close allso opened file
        fileWrite.close();
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Read file & store it's lines into ArrayList
        ArrayList<String> fileLines = readFile("testclass.txt");

        // If file was not loaded due to FileNotFoundException exception -> exit
        if (fileLines == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create reversed output.txt file
        createReversedFile("output.txt", fileLines);
    }

}
```

Comment: Spoon feeding the OP with a chunk of code does is not encouraged in Stack Overflow. It simply allows the OP to cut and paste without actually learning anything about the problem.